# Difficulty with unconventional rounding

Tags: rounding

I have a vector of values rounded to the nearest 10th, e.g

```
26.8, 23.3, 24.6, 27.1
```

I need to round each value to the nearest 0.5, in increments of 1, e.g.

```
26.5, 23.5, 24.5, 27.5
```

NOT to the nearest 0.5 in increments of 0.5, e.g.

```
27.0, 23.5, 24.5, 27.0
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Cheers,
Carly

Comment: why would 26.8 round to 26.5? that's a 0.3 difference, while rounding UP to 27.0 is 0.2. 0.3 > 0.2, so rounding down is NOT the "nearest" 0.5. ditto for 27.1 rounding to 27.5. wouldn't 27.0 be nearer?

Comment: 26.8 would round to 26.5 because that is a 0.3 difference, whereas rounding to 27.5 would be a 0.7 difference. So, rounding down would be to the nearest 0.5 (this is in increments of 1, not 0.5). - Carly

Comment: you examples AREN'T rounding to 27.5. unless you've totally mis-ordered those numbers. 26.8 -> 26.5 = good, 26.8 -> 27.0 = bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truncate and add `0.5`.

The numbers in the interval `[x.000, x.999]` are truncated to `x.0` and then adding `0.5` puts them at `x.5`.  This is sufficient for every interval, assuming that no extra requirements are placed on integer starting values.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply your number by 2, round it, then divide by 2 back.

Comment: This doesn't work as some rounded values divided by 2 are even (ex: 26.0) when I need the value rounded to the nearest 0.5 (in increments of 1).